# How to get a border to adapt and grow with extended content

Tags: html, css

I created the following fiddle..
https://jsfiddle.net/5mf989jL/

I am wondering how I can get the border on the right to adapt to the amount of content inside of the div selected from the left selection area.

The border css is from this class..

```
.dashboard_selection {
    float: right;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 73%;
    border: solid 1px #C0C0C0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

I know it is always the size it is now is because I have the `height` set, but if I don't do that the border doesn't show at all. What will I have to do?

Comment: Removing the `height` doesn't make the border disappear for me on Chrome or Firefox. I used this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jwozdr9/). Are you seeing this in a particular browser?

Comment: Wow... I'm not sure what I did when I tried to remove height, but you are right, that does work. Thanks!

Comment: @MarcBaumbach Do you know how I could get the panel class to be the full height of the page? It shows for the full height of the page, but if I scroll down it goes back to white.